# C do while issue

Tags: c

I can't understand why it doesn't looping even if I choose 1 or 2 or 3 in switch case.It just getting out of the program after the task,even if I didn't press E or e.
Need you help.

```
char ch;
do
{
    char* p;
    printf("Press 1 for qu. 1 \nPress 2 for qu. 2 \nPress 3 for qu. 3\nPress 'e' or 'E' to exit\n");
    scanf("%c", ch);
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '1':
        getMatrix();
        break;
    case '2':
        printf("\nPlease enter strDestination:\n");
        char str1[20], str2[20];
        scanf("%s", str1);
        printf("\nPlease enter strSource:\n");
        scanf("%s", str2);
        printf("%s\n", mystrcat(str1, str2));
        break;
    case '3':
        printf("\nPlease enter the first string (str):\n");
        char str3[20], str4[20];
        scanf("%s", str3);
        printf("\nPlease enter the sub string to search for(strSearch):\n");
        scanf("%s", str4);
        p = myStrstr(str3, str4);
        if (p != 0)
            printf("Location found: char %c index %d\n", *p, p - str3);
        else
            printf("strSearch is not found in str\n");
        break;
    case 'e' || 'E':
        system("exit");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Wrong input\n");
        break;
    }
} while (ch != 'e' || ch != 'E');
```

Comment: `ch != 'e' || ch != 'E'` is always true.

Comment: You are forgetting the `&` before the `ch`:  `scanf("%c", &ch);`

Comment: At a guess, you mean `!(ch == 'e' || ch == 'E')`

Comment: Remember that logical expressions in C uses [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So if `ch != 'e'` is true, then the whole expression is true. And if `ch != 'e'` is false, then `ch != 'E'` will be true. So no matter what you do you will have an expression that will always be true.

Comment: By the way, if you want to exit your program then `system("exit")` is not the way to do it.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &ch);` --> `scanf(" %c", &ch);` or use `int` type instead of getting trouble with newline.

Comment: thanks to all of you guys

Answer (score 2):

Three issues:

1. Your `scanf` is incorrect, you need to supply a *pointer* to `ch`. Use `scanf("%c", &ch);`
2. You mean `while (ch != 'e' && ch != 'E');`. This is easy to see if you consider the case when `ch` is `e`. In that case `ch != 'E'` is `1` so the loop still terminates.
3. Rewrite `case 'e' || 'E':` to `case 'e' : case 'E':` `'e' || 'E'` has the value 1 in C.